# SwiftUI list, Application performed a reentrant operation in its NSTableView delegate

Tags: list, macos, swiftui

I am attempting to append data to a SwiftUI list section. When I do this in the example code below, the console displays an warning which it forebodingly indicates, "will become an assert in the future."

```
struct ContentView: View {
  struct Rows: Hashable {
    let id: String
    let rows: [String]
  }

  @State var sections = [
    Rows(id: UUID().uuidString, rows: [])
  ]

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Button("Add Row") {
        let lastRows = sections.last!
        let rows = Rows(id: lastRows.id, rows: lastRows.rows + [UUID().uuidString])
        self.sections = [rows]
      }
      List {
        ForEach(sections, id: \.self) { exercise in
          Section(exercise.id) {
            ForEach(exercise.rows, id: \.self) { row in
              Text(row)
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you come up with a solution? 'Having the same problem, I update it from a different thread w/ a closure.

Comment: I think I found the error, it is "self.sections = [rows]", you are allowed to update the state variable sections with new entries but don't assign another new reference to it, this triggers the warning for me.

Comment: Wow, you just saved me a lot of time. Thanks for coming back to report that. I've been flustered for weeks.

Comment: Holy cow!!!!!!!

Comment: you mean "you are allowed to update the state variable sections with new entries but don't assign another new reference to it" like dont assigne with = , but use mutating functions on the array?